# How to not separate comma separated values in a column while using cursor?

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor

I am trying to use cursor to generate a csv file and send it as an email. The csv file that got generated  has values in a column separated. I don't want the values to be separated.

My Output : [Resulted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZkXu.png)

Desired Output : [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzjKP.png)

The table has two columns.

I am using a for loop for fetching the rows in the cursor :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GISPROD.POLE_CSV is
c_rec       VARCHAR2(100);
c_send      VARCHAR2(100);
vc_mess     VARCHAR2(32600);

crlf        VARCHAR2(2) := CHR(13) || CHR(10);

vc_headings VARCHAR2(500) := 'VISUAL_COMMENTS,POLE_STRENGTH';
file_name   VARCHAR2(100) := 'POLE_Report_' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 
'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') || '.csv';
conn        utl_smtp.connection;
BEGIN
FOR rec IN (
    SELECT  VISUAL_COMMENTS || ' , ' || POLE_STRENGTH  crlf AS eline
  FROM table_name
  WHERE import_date IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY inspect_date DESC, import_date 
)
LOOP
lh_mail.write_text(
  conn    => conn,
  message => rec.eline
);
END LOOP;
END;
```

I have tried using LISTAG AND concat, but it is not generating the desired output.

Comment: Provide sample data (i.e. *source*) and result based on that data. Also, if you post some code, it would help if it actually compiles - yours doesn't (what's that "crlf" thing doing there)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed the visual_comments column value in double quotation marks:

```sql
SELECT '"' || VISUAL_COMMENTS || '", ' || POLE_STRENGTH  || crlf AS eline
  FROM table_name
```